# Visual Studio designer crashes when showing control with async await in Load event

Tags: c#, visual-studio, async-await

I have a control named A with a (DevExpress) GridControl and I made the Load event async to get some initial data and provide them to GridView datasource. When i open the designer of parent control B which contains control A, Visual Studio 2015 crashes after some seconds and restarts.

Application runs smoothly without exceptions. The problem is only in the VS designer. The same happens if i place this code block in constructor. If i remove async await, or if I just don't use it in Load event everything works fine. It is like the designer runs the code in Load and fails

```cs
private async void MyControl_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    List<MyObject> myObjects = await Task.Run(() => MethodThatReturnsDataFromDb());
    BindDataToGridControl(myObjects);
}
```

Is await async supposed to be implemented differently when applied in Load event, is it VS designer bug or am I doing something horribly wrong?

Comment: Use the `this.DesignMode` property to skip code that is dangerous at design time.  Like loading data from a dbase.  Beware that a nested control might be in design mode, [look here](http://dotnetfacts.blogspot.com/2009/01/identifying-run-time-and-design-mode.html).

Comment: @HansPassant the current process name approach seems to be working. Can you post this as an answer so I can mark it solved? Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @HansPassant commented, the solution is to skip functionality you only need in runtime from DesignMode. Using `this.DesignMode` can help in that ([read here for details](http://dotnetfacts.blogspot.com/2009/01/identifying-run-time-and-design-mode.html)):

```
public new bool DesignMode
{
    get
    {
        return (System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName == "devenv");
    }
}
```

Simply referencing `this.DesignMode` without above implementation will not work in my case as the control is used within another control.

Afterwards the use is quite simple in the constructor or `Load` event:

```
if (!this.DesignMode)
{
    // Code that should run only in runtime and not in Design Mode
    ....
}
```